# Issue in my Opengl Vignette Shader in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to write an opengl shader that applies Vigenette Shader. But the issue I am facing is that it shows up a circle as you can see in the right image.

I want to find out what exactly must have been going wrong in my code.

I have also pasted the code below too.

[image]

**Code For My Vigenette Shader**

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
uniform sampler2D u_Vigenette;
uniform sampler2D u_Map;

varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;


void main()
{
 vec3 texel = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).rgb;
 texel.r = (texel.r == 1.0)?.9961:texel.r;
 texel.g = (texel.g == 1.0)?.9961:texel.g;
 texel.b = (texel.b == 1.0)?.9961:texel.b;

 texel = vec3(
                   texture2D(u_Map, vec2(texel.r, .16666)).r,
                   texture2D(u_Map, vec2(texel.g, .5)).g,
                   texture2D(u_Map, vec2(texel.b, .83333)).b);

 texel.r = (texel.r == 1.0)?.9961:texel.r;
 texel.g = (texel.g == 1.0)?.9961:texel.g;
 texel.b = (texel.b == 1.0)?.9961:texel.b;

 vec2 tc = (2.0 * v_TexCoordinate) - 1.0;
 float d = dot(tc, tc);
 vec2 lookup = vec2(d, texel.r);
 texel.r = texture2D(u_Vigenette, lookup).r;
 lookup.y = texel.g;
 texel.g = texture2D(u_Vigenette, lookup).g;
 lookup.y = texel.b;
 texel.b    = texture2D(u_Vigenette, lookup).b;

 gl_FragColor = vec4(texel, 1.0);
```

}

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess because there's not enough information to be sure, but I think that your code is expecting the result of

```
float d = dot(tc, tc);
```

to be in the range 0 to 1, but it's actually in the range 0 to 2.

Perhaps you want to rescale it, or perhaps the u_Vigenette texture is set to repeat instead of clamp to edge.